# Crash happened when the camera in my android app is launched (SHW-M110S)

Tags: android, camera, android-intent

Is there any differences between M100S and M110S?

My app uses camera component. codes are as follows

```
{  
  ComponentName compName = new ComponentName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.Camera");  

  Intent camIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);  
  actIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  
  actIntent.setComponent(compName);  
  StartActivity(actIntent);  
}
```

it works in M100S but not in M110S.
In M110S, app is crashed.

So I wonder if app is crashed because of the difference between the devices
or my codes are wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

package name is changed.

com.android.camera -> com.sec.android.app.camera

I checked it in logcat msg.
I'm not sure it is under specification of android.